# Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)

Tags: ruby

i have a `Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)` error popping up and i don't understand what it is or how to fix it. the full error is:

```
example.rb:19:in `write': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
    from example.rb:19:in `print'
    from example.rb:19
```

line 19 of my code is:

```
vari.print("x=" + my_val + "&y=1&z=Add+Num\r\n")
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It means that whatever connection print is outputting to is no longer connected.  Presumably the program began as input to some other program:

```
 % ruby_program | another_program
```

What's happened is that `another_program` has exited sometime before the `print` in question.

Comment: actually, this code is all for an http request. does that just mean the server isn't connected at that point? this seems to be happening randomly.

Comment: I don't know much about ruby, but EPIPE maybe could be a network disconnection.  On Linux I would expect the error would be ENETRESET, ECONNABORTED, ECONNRESET, ENOTCONN, or ESHUTDOWN for that condition.

Comment: @sepiroth: `EPIPE` is _system_-defined; it is the exit code reported by a system call that triggered the `SIGPIPE` signal, which typically indicates that the process at the _reading_ end of  a _pipe_ has exited (while the _writing_ end is still trying to write to the pipe); additionally, in a _network_ context,
[this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Operation-Error-Signals) states: "Another cause of `SIGPIPE` is when you try to output to a _socket_ that isn’t connected. See [Sending Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Sending-Data)".

Comment: Looks like ruby 2.2 has fixed `open3` to silently ignore `EPIPE`, see https://fossies.org/diffs/ruby/2.1.5_vs_2.2.0/lib/open3.rb-diff.html

Answer (score 19):

**Note:**

- The 1st section **applies to Ruby scripts designed to act as *terminal-based command-line utilities***, assuming they **require *no custom handling or cleanup* on receiving `SIGPIPE`**, and assuming that you want them to exhibit the behavior of standard Unix utilities such as `cat`, which ***terminate quietly* with a *specific exit code*** when receiving `SIGPIPE`.
- The 2nd section is for scripts that **require *custom handling* of `SIGPIPE`, such as *explicit cleanup* and (conditional) *output of error messages***.

---

#### Opting into the *system's default handling* of `SIGPIPE`:

To complement [wallyk's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1807380/45375) and [tokland's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15430214/45375):

If you want your script to **exhibit the system's *default* behavior**, as **most Unix utilities (e.g., `cat`) do**, use

```
Signal.trap("SIGPIPE", "SYSTEM_DEFAULT")
```

at the beginning of your script.

Now, when your script receives the `SIGPIPE` signal (on Unix-like systems), the system's default behavior will:

- quietly **terminate** your script
- report **exit code `141`** (which is calculated as `128` (indicating termination by *signal*) + `13` (`SIGPIPE`'s *number*))

(By contrast, `Signal.trap("PIPE", "EXIT")` would report exit code `0`, on receiving the signal, which indicates *success*.)

Note that in a *shell* context the exit code is often not apparent in a command such as `ruby examble.rb | head`, because the shell (by default) only reports the *last* command's exit code.

In `bash`, you can examine `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` to see the exit codes of *all* commands in the pipeline.

---

**Minimal example** (run from `bash`):

```
ruby -e "Signal.trap('PIPE','SYSTEM_DEFAULT');(1..1e5).each do|i| puts i end" | head
```

The Ruby code tries to output 100,000 lines, but `head` only outputs the first 10 lines and then exits, which closes the read end of the pipe that connects the two commands.

The next time the Ruby code tries to the write end of that now broken pipe (after filling up the pipeline buffer), it triggers signal `SIGPIPE`, which terminates the Ruby process quietly, with exit code `141`, which you can verify with `echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` afterwards.

By contrast, if you removed `Signal.trap('PIPE','SYSTEM_DEFAULT')`, i.e. with Ruby's *default* behavior, the command would break noisily (several lines of stderr output), and the exit code would be the nondescript `1`.

---

#### Custom handling of `SIGPIPE`:

The following builds on [donovan.lampa's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082444/45375) and adds an improvement suggested by
 [Kimmo Lehto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681520/kimmo-lehto), who points out that, **depending on your script's purpose, receiving `SIGPIPE` shouldn't always terminate *quietly*, because it may indicate a *legitimate error condition***, notably in network code such as code for downloading a file from the internet.
He recommends the following idiom for that scenario:

```
begin

  # ... The code that could trigger SIGPIPE

rescue Errno::EPIPE

  # ... perform any cleanup, logging, ... here

  # Raise an exception - which translates into stderr output -
  # but only when outputting directly to a terminal.
  # That way, failure is quiet inside a pipeline, such as when
  # piping to standard utility `head`, where SIGPIPE is an expected
  # condition.
  raise if $stdout.tty?
  # If the stack trace that the `raise` call results in is too noisy
  # use something like the following instead, which outputs just the
  # error message itself to stderr: 
  #      $stderr.puts $! if $stdout.tty?
  # Or, even simpler:
  #      warn $! if $stdout.tty?


  # Exit with the usual exit code that indicates termination by SIGPIPE
  exit 141

end
```

As a one-liner:

```
... rescue Errno::EPIPE raise if $stdout.tty?; exit 141
```

Note: Rescuing `Errno::EPIPE` works, because if the signal is ignored, the system call writing to the pipeline *returns to the caller* (instead of the caller process getting *terminated*), namely with standard error *code* `EPIPE`, which Ruby surfaces as exception `Errno::EPIPE`.

Comment: excelent explanation, chapeaux.

Answer (score 15):

@wallyk is right on the problem. One solution is to capture the signal with [Signal.trap](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Signal.html#method-c-trap):

```
Signal.trap("PIPE", "EXIT")
```

If you are aware of some problem with this approach, please add a comment below.

Comment: That's handy, but note that the exit code of the Ruby process will be `0`, not the usual `141` (though that may not matter, depending on use case)

Answer (score 15):

Although signal traps do work, as tokland said, they are defined application wide and can cause some unexpected behavior if you want to handle a broken pipe in some other way somewhere else in your app.

I'd suggest just using a standard rescue since the error still inherits from StandardError. More about this module of errors: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Errno.html

Example:

```
begin
  vari.print("x=" + my_val + "&y=1&z=Add+Num\r\n")
rescue Errno::EPIPE
  puts "Connection broke!"
end
```

**Edit:** It's important to note (as @mklement0 does in the comments) that if you were originally piping your output using puts to something expecting output on STDOUT, the final puts in the code above will raise another Errno::EPIPE exception. It's probably better practice to use STDERR.puts anyway.

```
begin
  vari.print("x=" + my_val + "&y=1&z=Add+Num\r\n")
rescue Errno::EPIPE
  STDERR.puts "Connection broke!"
end
```

Comment: Sounds sensible, but in practice (Ruby 2.0.0) I've been unable to catch this error; try `ruby -e 'begin; puts (1..10000).map { |n| "line #{n}" }; rescue Errno::EPIPE; puts "No can do: #{$!.message}"; end' | head` - it still breaks; Even trying to rescue `Exception` doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @mklement0 You are actually rescuing the exception, but the exception gets raised again withinin your rescue statement because you are trying to write your custom exception string to STDOUT which is still being piped to head (and whose pipe to head has been broken already). If you run this `ruby -e 'begin; puts (1..10000).map { |n| "line #{n}" }; rescue Errno::EPIPE; STDERR.puts "No can do: #{$!.message}"; end' | head` you'll see that it does indeed rescue the original Errno::EPIPE exception.