# RSpec Broken pipe

Tags: ruby, rspec, pipe

I'm having errors in some tests but the error themselves seem to be covered up by this error coming from

```
/home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/
formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:162:in `write': 
Broken pipe - <STDOUT> (Errno::EPIPE)
```

fyi, I run the test and then pipe out the results to less as there's a lot of output.

How can I resolve this?

I've updated RSpec and tried different versions of ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0 but to no avail.

Comment: see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807355/broken-pipe-errnoepipe

Comment: Here is more [hints](https://www.google.co.in/#q=Broken+pipe+-+%3CSTDOUT%3E+(Errno:%3AEPIPE)).... Hope you will get your answer...

Comment: How are you executing your tests? It looks like you might be doing something like `rspec | less` and then exiting out of less.

Comment: Shepmaster, yeah the pipe to less was the issue!  Post and I'll accept...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you executing your tests? It looks like you might be doing something like `rspec | less` and then exiting out of less. This closes the pipe while RSpec is still printing to it.

Comment: Yes this was **exactly** the issue!