# How to debug broken pipe on AngularJS + Ruby on Rails + PostgreSQL stack when saving very large string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, postgresql, leap-motion

I am working on a web app using a stack consisting of the following:

LeapJS + AngularJS + Ruby on Rails + PostgreSQL

I am new to Ruby. LeapJS is a JS library for working with the [Leap Motion](https://leapmotion.com) controller.

The application is attempting to capture hand motion data and save it to the database. However, I am running into a problem when attempting to save the data. Often times, each gesture will be a string that is over 250KB. When I do tests with smaller test strings, the data seems to save properly. Therefore, I think that the problem must have something to do with the size of the string. The PostgreSQL field into which the data is being saved is of type `text`.

This is the error message I am getting from Ruby when something goes awry. If anyone with a bit more Ruby experience than I has any advice about where to start debugging, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
Started POST "/api/gestures" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-21 15:32:48 -0800
Processing by GesturesController#create as HTML

Errno::EPIPE (Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDERR>):
  /Users/jefffohl/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:610:in `write'
  /Users/jefffohl/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:610:in `warn'
  /Users/jefffohl/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:610:in `rescue in write'
  /Users/jefffohl/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:594:in `write'
  /Users/jefffohl/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:378:in `add'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/logger.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in broadcast'
  /Users/jefffohl/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:452:in `error'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:85:in `rescue in finish'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:83:in `finish'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:102:in `finish'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:46:in `block in finish'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:46:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:46:in `finish'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:36:in `finish'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:25:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:28:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/jefffohl/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/jefffohl/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/jefffohl/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: have you looked into using http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Signal.html#method-c-trap  ?

Comment: Here is a good post on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807355/broken-pipe-errnoepipe

Comment: @ruby_newbie thanks for the tips. Yes, it appears that postgres is crapping out for some reason - perhaps due to the size of the data (though it doesn't seem close to postgres' limits). not sure if it is related to ruby or not.