# Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe exception is raised

Tags: ruby, pipe, fork

```
if @block
  rd, wr = IO.pipe
  @pid = fork do
    $0 = "Forked child from Page #{@path}"
    rd.close
    result = @block.call(@resp.body)
    begin
    wr.write Marshal.dump(result)
  end
  wr.close
```

This is a pretty standard way to share a pipe with a fork, yet as soon as `rd.close` is called it breaks the pipe for `wr` to use. Up until that line the pipe works as it should (I ran it line by line with Pry). As far as I'm aware it is good practice to close the reader inside the fork to stop it interfering with EOF being sent (I don't know why that works I just know that's the practice).

This is part of a library I call into a production app. The library's own specs never encounter this even though they run very similar code (only the `@block` and `@resp` will differ to any great degree). Obviously the app's code is more complex but I can't see how it would be interfering with this code. I searched through other libraries required by the app to see if any were trapping signals that might interfere with this but I found nothing.

Can anyone suggest what the problem could be or a work around for it? I've tried catching the `Errno::EPIPE` exception and `retry`ing but that doesn't fix it, reopening the pipe (I'm not entirely sure how to do that anyway as after the fork occurs it'd be hard to link it to the main process), emptying the block so it doesn't do any work… still no joy.

I have also found (via a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1807355/335847)) that Ruby's Open3 in the standard library silently rescues and drops `Errno::EPIPE` but no reason was given with the commit message. I don't know if it is related.
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e3c288569833b6777e7ecc0bbc26f8e6ca8f2ba7/lib/open3.rb#L268

Comment: Note that `fork` returns twice, once in the parent (returning the child's pid) and once in the child (returning nil). You are therefore supposed to call `fork` within a conditional, i.e.: `if fork then <parent code> else <child code> end`. The docs for [`IO.pipe`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-pipe) contain an example.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. It does, but that's not the only way to structure the code, for example [this code](https://www.sitepoint.com/forking-ipc-ruby-part-ii/) is very similar to mine. The writer is closed immediately after the fork in my code, no need for an if/else.

Comment: You're right, I've never used `fork`'s block form.

Comment: Are you sure the main process (which makes `fork` call) exists when child tries to write to the pipe? You cannot write to a pipe if there is no any reader and vise versa. For instance you can block parent process and wait for child death with `Process#wait` call.

Comment: @andrykonchin The library is running a loop with `Process.waitpid2(-1, Process::WNOHANG)` which I thought should be mopping up all the processes but I think you're on to something as I fully blocked in calling code and the error didn't occur… though it did get stuck in an infinite loop. If it's not one thing… :-)

Comment: @andrykonchin I'll look into that a bit more and if that's really the case I'll be happy to award you the bounty, you prompted the right move forward that I needed! Won't be long.

Comment: This might be a redundant questions - but you are saving the `rd` and `wr` variables (from `rd, wr = IO.pipe`) somewhere where they can be accessed beyond the scope of the `if` statement, right? I mean, you aren't leaving them to the mercy of the GC that might close them and free their memory before the `fork`ed process writes to `wr`, right?

Comment: @Myst All processing is finished within the `if` block, and an empty or trivial block should finish processing almost immediately. The GC shouldn't be that quick, should it? The other thing that's puzzling me is how the pipe is broken immediately after closing `rd`. That shouldn't happen at all.

Comment: @iain , the GC has optimizations for short scoped variables, meaning it can be very fast for short function calls or blocks where a temporary variable is used. The pipe will be broken the moment no one has an open reference to `rd`. Try reading from `rd` before it goes out of scope and see if it helps.

Comment: @iain Have you closed the `wr` in the parent process? It should be closed after fork.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @AetherusZhou Yes, immediately.

Comment: @Stefan I can't because the app isn't open source, but the calling library with the fork in is here https://github.com/yb66/sinatra-export/tree/fibred. It's likely to have some (other) glaring mistakes but the [broken pipe part shouldn't break after `rd.close` regardless](https://github.com/yb66/sinatra-export/blob/fibred/lib/sinatra/export/page.rb#L110).

Comment: Can you provide an abstraction of the actual code which is not proprietary and reproduces the problem?  It seems to me you are missing an `end` statement, there's a `begin` with no `end` inside the forked block.  This would probably mean the `wr.close` executes in the forked process, which you do not want.

Comment: Is this related to the comments in IO.pipe rdoc? [io.pipe](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-pipe). It reads: "In the example below, the two processes close the ends of the pipe that they are not using. This is not just a cosmetic nicety. The read end of a pipe will not generate an end of file condition if there are any writers with the pipe still open. In the case of the parent process, the rd.read will never return if it does not first issue a wr.close."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this has taken so long to get answered. I suspect this is "fixed" in current versions of ruby as I was unable to replicate using simplified versions of your code, but for future reference, here's how I would have structured the code:

```
def test_my_pipes
 rd, wr = IO.pipe  
 fork do  
   rd.close
   sleep 5
   wr.write "Hello world"
   wr.close
 end    
 wr.close  # essential
 puts "Waiting for sleepy fork"
 puts rd.read
 rd.close
end
```

Note that both inside and outside the fork block, we close both rd and wr. In actual fact, only the parent process `wr.close` is essential, but definitely better to close all the ends of the pipe when not needed.

If this code still breaks, would be interested to see what versions of ruby they break for.

Comment: It's been so long that I'd forgotten why I'd asked! I just checked out the library that was having trouble and ran the specs with MRI v2.6.3 and it's all green. I may have to play around to find the problem again but till then, you can have the tick because you appear to be right and it was a very helpful nudge :)

Comment: Haha, glad I helped! Thanks for the tick :D