# Ruby Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDOUT>

Tags: ruby, pipe, stdout

while trying to run a ruby program and piping the output to another program like this:

```
ruby hello.rb | whoami
```

The command `whoami` is executed first as expected, but after that, hello.rb crashes with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from p.rb:2:in `<main>'
    1: from p.rb:2:in `print'
p.rb:2:in `write': Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDOUT> (Errno::EPIPE)
```

This happens only when `STDOUT.sync` is set to `true`

```
STDOUT.sync = true
STDOUT.print "Hello!"
```

[and a similar error is raised with `STDOUT.flush` after `STDOUT.puts` when piped to another program]

What is the reason behind this crash?

Comment: The issues is that `whoami` is writing to STDOUT, and by flushing the buffer your ruby script is now writing to a broken pipe. Here is quite a good writeup on the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30103307/1954610

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Introduction

Firstly, an explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807355/broken-pipe-errnoepipe).

Anyways, here's my thought...

When a pipe is used like this:

```
a | b
```

Both a and b are executed [concurrently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37597/274717). b waits for standard input from a.

Speaking of `Errno::EPIPE`, The [Linux man page of write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) says:

> EPIPE  fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is
>             closed.  When this happens the writing process will also
>             receive a SIGPIPE signal.  (Thus, the write return value is
>             seen only if the program catches, blocks or ignores this
>             signal.)

Talking about the problem in the question:
When the program `whoami` is run, it exits and no longer accepts standard inputs that ruby program `hello.rb` is sending - resulting in a broken pipe.

**Here I wrote 2 ruby programs, named p.rb and q.rb to test that:**

- p.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
print ?* * 100_000
```

- q.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
exit! 0
```

**Running:**

```
bash[~] $ ruby p.rb | ruby q.rb

Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from p.rb:2:in `<main>'
    1: from p.rb:2:in `print'
p.rb:2:in `write': Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDOUT> (Errno::EPIPE)
```

### Let's change the code of *q.rb* a bit, so that it accepts inputs:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
STDIN.gets
```

**Running:**

```
bash[~] $ ruby p.rb | ruby q.rb
```

Right, it displays nothing actually. The reason is that q.rb now waits for standard inputs. **Apparently, the waiting is what matters the most here**. Now, p.rb will not crash with even with `STDOUT.sync` or `STDOUT.flush` when piped to this q.rb.

### Another Example:

- p.rb

```
STDOUT.sync = true
loop until print("\e[2K<<<#{Time.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S:%2N')}>>>\r")
```

[warning: the loop without sleep may bring up your CPU usage]

- q.rb

```
sleep 3
```

**Running:**

```
bash[~] $ time ruby p.rb | q.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from p.rb:2:in `<main>'
    1: from p.rb:2:in `print'
p.rb:2:in `write': Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDOUT> (Errno::EPIPE)

real    0m3.186s
user    0m0.282s
sys 0m0.083s
```

You see the program crashed after 3 seconds. It will crash after 5.1 seconds if q.rb had `sleep 5`. Similarly `sleep 0` in *q.rb* will crash *p.rb* after 0.1 seconds. I guess the additional 0.1 seconds depends on the system because **my system takes 0.1 seconds to load the ruby interpreter.**

I wrote p.cr and q.cr Crystal programs to test. Crystal is [compiled](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/using_the_compiler/) and doesn't take the long 0.1 seconds to load up.

### The Crystal Programs:

- p.cr

```
STDOUT.sync = true
loop do print("\e[2KHi!\r") end rescue exit
```

- q.cr

```
sleep 3
```

I compiled them, and ran:

```
bash[~] $ time ./p | ./q

real    0m3.013s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.019s
```

The binary *./p*, in very close to 3 seconds, handles `Unhandled exception: Error writing file: Broken pipe (Errno)` and exits. Again, 0.01 seconds may be taken by the two crystal programs to execute and maybe the Kernel also takes a bit time to run the processes.

Also note that `STDERR#print`, `STDERR#puts`, `STDERR#putc`, `STDERR#printf`, `STDERR#write`, `STDERR#syswrite` doesn't raise Errno::EPIPE even if the output is in sync.

### Conclusion

Pipe is [arcane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37513/274717). Setting `STDOUT#sync` to true or using `STDOUT#flush` flushes all buffered data to the underlying operating system.

When running `hello.rb | whoami`, without sync, I can write 8191 bytes of data, and the program *hello.rb* doesn't crash. But with sync, writing 1 byte via pipe will crash *hello.rb*.

So when *hello.rb* synchronizes standard outputs with the piped program `whoami`, and `whoami` doesn't wait for *hello.rb*; *hello.rb* raises `Errno::EPIPE` because the pipe between these two programs is broken (correct me if I am lost here).